# Does Azure API management have metering capabilities - for example: measure by number of bytes transferred, or by number of API calls?

Tags: azure-api-management

Would like to provide billing using metrics that are not based on time (min, hours).
Can Azure API management do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are metrics for total requests in azure monitor at service level.

Comment: And there is reporting API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/reports